# asp.net DropDownList set SelectedValue NOT working

Tags: c#, asp.net, dropdown, selectedvalue

I have a user-control contains a DropDownList, and this user-control is used inside another one. I am passing the selected value to the drop-down from the outer user control to the inner one, and I am tracking the value passed (during debugging) and the value is passed correctly, but at least the value is NOT set correctly!

**Here is the code of the outer user-control**

```
public int SelectedPhoneNumberCountryCode
{
    get { return ucRecoveryPhoneNumber.SelectedPhoneNumberCountryCode; }
    set { ucRecoveryPhoneNumber.SelectedPhoneNumberCountryCode = value; }
}
```

**And this is the code of the inner user-control (ucRecoveryPhoneNumber)**

```
public int SelectedPhoneNumberCountryCode
{
    get { return int.Parse(DdlCountryPhoneCodes.SelectedValue); }
    set { DdlCountryPhoneCodes.SelectedValue = value.ToString(); }
}
```

At the Page_Load, the value is passed correctly until the last step, but it is not set correctly! and the drop-down is always selected as the first value (default one).

**Q** What is wrong with this code? or What should be done to make it work?

Comment: Can you show the aspx markup also?

Comment: Thanx [@VDWWD](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5836671/vdwwd), there is nothing to do now, the problem was from my side; as there was another code that refills the drop-down again and causing the selected value to be reset to the default value.